# How to limit printer settings for networked CUPS printer?

Tags: printing, cups

We have a CUPS based color laser printer. Our colleagues often tweak their print settings, resulting in non optimal configurations. E.g. they change the color reproduction so that even black and white text will be printed in full CMYK. This can be avoided by setting the "Color reproduction" CUPS printer setting. However, right now this can be overriden by the user. Is there a possibility to force this setting on the CUPS server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're sharing your cups server. Normally, the user should not be able to change printer settings on the cups server as that typically requires admin privileges.

Comment: No, these are the normal printer driver properties. Not the CUPS settings like URI of the printer, printer driver etc.